# What are possible explanations for fuel being expelled in this video?

Tags: fuel, incidents, fuel-systems, fuel-dumping

In [another question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/38963/would-a-fuel-leak-at-the-gate-be-a-reportable-incident), I asked about whether or not a fuel spill would be reportable or not. The answer was "no", because the aircraft was not in flight.

What are the possible causes of the [spill demonstrated by this video](https://youtu.be/2q3VE5L7L4s)?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can think of 4 possible causes, 3 of which can probably be discounted.

1. Tank venting. The fuel system is designed to deliberately "leak" if
   the tanks are overfilled or, the fuel expands due to temperature
   changes. Whilst I haven't seen this happen on a B767, I have seen it
   on numerous other types and when it happens, it does not gush out
   like it does in this video.  It's more of a seep of fuel which drips
   off the underside.  Whilst it can be a lot of fuel, this video does
   not fit a venting scenario.  Additionally, the flight crew would be
   very familiar with venting which would be a normal event and would
   not have abandoned the flight.
2. A fuel leak such as a ruptured pipe, a failed seal and so on.  I
   would expect to see fuel ejected like this but only from a
   pressurised part of the system, downstream of the fuel pumps.  The
   location of this leak is not from a pressurised part of the fuel
   system and in my opinion, there is simply too much fuel for it to be
   a result of gravity.  It also appears to be coming from a nozzle
   rather than seepage
3. As can be seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Kc1agd6aEs), the source of the fuel is
   coincident with the location of the fuel dump nozzle.  It is
   possible that the crew accidentally activated the fuel dump but
   unlikely (inconceivable?).  The switches are very clearly surrounded
   with "don't touch this" markings and require two separate switches
   to be activated.  Additionally, the jettison valve switches are
   "guarded" such that you have to lift a spring loaded flap up in
   order to be able to press the button.
4. The [APU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_power_unit) draws it's fuel from the left main tank. This flight was
   close to the  maximum range of a 767 so  would have been at or close
   to maximum fuel load. If the APU had been running for a long time,
   longer than expected, it's possible that the crew started a fuel
   transfer to balance the tanks by pumping fuel from the right tank to
   the left tank and forgot to switch the transfer off.  This could
   have pressurised the left tank causing fuel to overflow into the
   [surge tank](http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~johnm/Three-Lightbursts/Flammable767.JPG) and vent out (the surge tank vent is also very close
   to the jettison nozzle).  I believe that this is the most likely scenario.

This is the only authoritative source I could find [showing the fuel jettison switches.](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aircraft/amt_airframe_handbook/media/ama_ch14.pdf)

All supposition of course but a strange incident.  I'm sure there may be other possible causes and I'm sure that comments and other answers might expand on this.

Comment: @mins Hey Mins, that's a good answer in my view and great information.  I don't want to steal your work.  Why don't you post it here?

Answer (score 2):

This particular 767 does not have the fuel jettison nozzles installed (most 767-200s don't have them) and fuel can not be transferred between tanks from the cockpit (can be done from the fuel panel on the left wing). The fuel is discharging from the vent in the surge tank, I suspect this happened during manual refueling as the overfill sensors would shut off fuel to that tank in auto.

The only other likely scenario would be one or more of the check valves between the left tank fuel pumps and center tank pumps had failed open with fuel in the center tank and the center fuel (override) pumps on.

Comment: Welcome to Av.se!